# jquery rotate div and make it move up.

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

Hi guys. I've got an image which I have put inside of a div. Basically I am trying to figure out how to rotate it and then make it move. I have tried some code but it's not working. Any help on this matter would be great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $elie = $("#super");
    rotate(22);

    function rotate(degree) {        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            rotate(++degree);
        },22);
    }
});
</script>
```

For some reason that code is not working and making the image rotate. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If your using Firefox look at Firebugs console or if using Chrome look in that error console.

Comment: Thank you thats great i misplaced one of the java libareys. Could you please answer the second part of the question and that is how do i make it stop at an agle and them make it move? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because you are calling the function before defining it.